# Item transfer between Listboxes Last Row Issue

Tags: vba, listboxitem

I have a listbox with values that I want to move to another listbox so the user can sort the items. When the last item is selected, it only moves that item and erases the values above it. How can I have it function like the other items in the list?

FYI, it is a single item selection, if that changes anything

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Private Sub Add_Click()
 Dim x As Integer, count As Integer
  count = Me.Unsorted.ListCount
    For x = 0 To count
        If Me.Unsorted.Selected(x) = True Then
            Me.Sorted.AddItem Me.Unsorted.List(x)
        End If
    Next x

    For x = count To 0 Step -1
        If Me.Unsorted.Selected(x) = True Then
            Me.Unsorted.RemoveItem x
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this

```
Private Sub Add_Click()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim nSelecteds As Long

    With Me
        With .Unsorted
            ReDim selecteds(1 To .ListCount) As Long
            For x = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If .Selected(x) Then
                    nSelecteds = nSelecteds + 1
                    selecteds(nSelecteds) = x
                    Me.Sorted.AddItem .List(x)
                End If
            Next x
            If nSelecteds > 0 Then
                For x = 1 To nSelecteds
                    .RemoveItem selecteds(x)
                Next x
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Liiikkee a gllovee. Thanks!!

Comment: you are welcome. BTW I wrote the code to account for a multiselect listbox also. should it be a single select listbox, it can be reduced